# Can someone explain why this this for loop prints out this specific pattern?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I thought I had a good understanding of for loops, but now that I have started to try looping patterns with for loops, things have gotten a lot more confusing. For example, I know that the following code will print out:

`for (var line =  “#”; line.length < 8; line += “#”)`
`console.log(line);`

Output will be:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

This is what I understand so far about this loop:

1. Firstly, the loop is initialized by creating a variable “line” to store the value “#” which is only one character.
2. Next, “line.length<8” checks that the length of the string stored in the variable “line” is less than 8 characters long.
3. The third part “line += “#”” updates the value stored in the line variable by adding “#” for each iteration that line.length<8 is true.
4. The length of the string (and therefore line.length) is being updated for each iteration of the loop because a “#” value is being added each time.

Can someone explain to me why # is being added once, then twice, then three times etc. From the (incorrect) understanding that I have, I keep thinking that it’ll look like:

```
#1
#2
#3
```

etc.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting you, this seems like a valid question

Comment: At what point do you think does `"#"` get added more than one time in one iteration?

Comment: First iterstion log # second ## third ###... because console.log prints in one new line each time is called.

Comment: Can you help us out by explaining why you think it will print a single `#` every time? Perhaps show us the value of line before/after each iteration, and the output

Comment: I’m really not sure what you don’t understand about how this loop works. Your third point already explains it perfectly: “[t]he third part `line += "#"` updates the value stored in the `line` variable by adding `"#"` for each iteration”.

Comment: Incidentily if you wanted to produce the output you expected you could write `console.log('#' + line.length);` although most would change the for loop  to `for(var i= 0; i <8; i++ ) console.log('#' + i)`

Comment: `+` is not only *addition* operator. It is also *concatenation* operator. So `'#' + '#'` makes `'##'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop, there are three statements, separated by semicolons.

The first statement is an initialization, as you correctly identified.

The second statement is a condition. This is checked before every iteration, and will execute the loop code (in this case, `console.log`) if the condition is true.

The last statement is executed after every iteration.

In your loop, `line` is initialized to "#". Then, it checks if `line.length < 8`. Since it is, `console.log` is called. Then, `line += "#"` is executed, which adds "#" to the end of line. At this point, `line` is `"##"`. It will then check if `line.length < 8`, and so on, until the condition isn't true.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) might help your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you explained it well yourself.

> 3.The third part “line += “#”” updates the value stored in the line variable > by adding “#” for each iteration that line.length<8 is true.

Each time through the loop one additional # is being concatenated to the end of the string. It starts as #, then ##, then ###.

When we call

```
console.log(line);
```

it just prints the string itself, it has nothing to do with the length of the string, or any line number.

At the start of each pass, a check is made on the length of the string. In this case the length is simply how many # are in the string.

Answer (score 0):

the var Line persists throughout the loop so if you had ## and again the loop adds # you end up with ###. In this case you are calling .length on a string which gives you the length of the string in individual characters.

so essentially what you are asking the loop to do is append a # to line until there are 8 of them and stop.

Hope this helps